# Error CallBack URL in Twitter app with Firebase

Tags: twitter, callback, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a Twitter app with Firebase but the CallBack URL of firebase always return

```
Error
The client application failed validation: Not a valid URL format.
```

but in the [documentation of firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/twitter.html), it guides me put Callback URL:

```
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/heyfriend/auth/twitter/callback
```

I'm in total loss to find out the problem with Callback URL. Help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found problem. It is: website and callback should match